# Datatable with nested (tibble) child rows

Tags: html, r, dplyr, dt

I would like to use R (`DT::datatable()` function) to show child rows on click. I found this function `varsExplore::datatable2()`, but it does not work with nested list columns.

```
library(tidyverse); library(DT); library(varsExplore)

starwars2 <- starwars %>% dplyr::select(-films:-starships)

# this example works using varsExplore::datatable2
starwars2 %>% varsExplore::datatable2(vars = names(starwars)[4:11])

# this does not work
starwars2 %>% 
  nest(NData = hair_color:species) %>% varsExplore::datatable2(vars = "NData")
          # Error in varsExplore::datatable2(., vars = "NData") : 
          #  list columns are not supported in datatable2()
```

My data contains nested columns (each is a tibble) and I would like to use `DT` to show the content of selected nested column(s) after a click. My data looks like this (however, each item in the `NData` column has multiple rows):

```
starwars2 %>% nest(NData = hair_color:species)

# A tibble: 87 × 4
   name               height  mass NData           
   <chr>               <int> <dbl> <list>          
 1 Luke Skywalker        172    77 <tibble [1 × 8]>
 2 C-3PO                 167    75 <tibble [1 × 8]>
 3 R2-D2                  96    32 <tibble [1 × 8]>
 4 Darth Vader           202   136 <tibble [1 × 8]>
 5 Leia Organa           150    49 <tibble [1 × 8]>
 6 Owen Lars             178   120 <tibble [1 × 8]>
 7 Beru Whitesun lars    165    75 <tibble [1 × 8]>
 8 R5-D4                  97    32 <tibble [1 × 8]>
 9 Biggs Darklighter     183    84 <tibble [1 × 8]>
10 Obi-Wan Kenobi        182    77 <tibble [1 × 8]>
```

I encounter examples that implement this using `shiny apps`. However, I would like to implement this without a shiny app (i.e. saving this as a standard HTML document).

Thanks

Comment: you could also have a look at `reactable` package, if that would also be an option. https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#expand-on-click

Comment: Can you give a small piece of your tibble with `dput` please.

Comment: The data shown in the example is automatically loaded from the tidyverse package @StéphaneLaurent
I am unaware of the `reactable` package. I will explore it.. Thanks.. @Julian

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly with the method shown on [my blog](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/DT_childTables.html).

Copy the code given in the blog post. Use the `NestedData` function like this:

```
dat <- starwars2 %>% select(-NData)
children <- starwars2[["NData"]]
Dat <- NestedData(dat, children)
```

[image]